# Need help in NodeJs and MongoDB problem (Mongoose populate is not working)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nodes, populate

Here is my schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const finalDocument = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  Properties: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Properties",
  },
  borrower: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "borrowers",
  },
});

var FinalDocuments = mongoose.model("finalDocument", finalDocument);
module.exports = FinalDocuments;
```

and here are my routes.

```
finalDocument
    .find({})
    .populate("borrower")
    .exec()
    .then((brws) => {
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      res.json(brws);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("error in getting borrowers", err);
    });
```

and when I am calling this route, borrower is not populated. I am attaching the picture of Postman.

Comment: Can you also add other relevant schemas to the question?

Comment: The picture of your Postman application appears to be missing from the question.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Have you tried running this code independently of the Node application, to see if they work there? If you run a Mongoose/Mongo application on the console it is much easier to debug.

Comment: i haven't tried that, but this is my postman response:

[
    {
        "_id": "633c961cd9378702fa818925",
        "name": "hi",
        "__v": 0
    }
]

Comment: Please add your Postman response, in a code block, in the post itself (click the Edit link). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There seems no problem with your code.

***Possible reasons are:***

1. The collection name you mentioned in the *ref =>* `borrower: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "borrowers", }` in your schema may be spelling mistake or defined wrong schema name
2. May be borrowers collection doesn't have documents
3. Update your mongoose version and check